# EMACS-Live + Slime error at startup

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, ubuntu

Ok, I must be missing something obvious. I'm getting stuck since yesterday to launch Emacs-live + slime.
I'm using EMACS 24.3.1, installed Emacs-live and it worked well (if I start emacs-live without Slime it works), downloaded Slime-Pack from git and added this line to .emacs-live.el

> (live-append-packs '(~/.live-packs/slime-pack/))

I'm on a virtual machine under Kubuntu, and here's the error message I got :

> An error occured while loading '/home/xxx/.emacs.d/init.el':
>
> error: Recursive 'require' for feature 'slime'

When I run EMACS with --debug-init :

> ad-0rig-require(slime nil nil)
>
> require(slime)

I already tried many times to delete EMACS + slime pack + all config files/folders for EMACS but nothing worked... Ho despair !

I tried to create a new user in order to start from scratch, reinstall all, and I haven't include my profile into emacs-live.el, only the slime-pack ==> same result. Rah.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/thephoeron/slime-pack

Comment: The error message certainly indicates an error in your `init.el` and the other information you have supplied seems tangential at best.

Comment: Yes, this one.
I already looked into the init.el, but I can't fully read LISP (in fact i'm installing emacs-live in order to learn LISP).
I'll take another look, thanks for your reactivity.

Comment: We can.  If you have not modified the file, probably no point in including it here, though.

Comment: No I haven't modified anything, just following the steps from here : http://learnlispthehardway.org/book/1-01-09-emacs-live/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHAMPAGNE !!! Reinstalled my VM, done all steps one by one and that wasn't ok. I had to launch twice the "bash <(curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/overton..." command line once all other steps was executed and say "No" to the question asking if I want to create a personnal folder. Don't know if that was important however.
I also removed my personnal pack from emacs-live.el and voila ! :)

I hope that will help other people having the same issue.